# Is there a way to add hyperlinks from within JSON data?

Tags: json, express, hyperlink, pug

I am trying to implement a proof of concept for a personal project which is a hypertextual blog. The project is built using expressjs and I am storing the blog data in a JSON file. Part of the structure of the JSON file is as follows:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name_kanji": "井上和 ",
        [...]
        "trivia": [ "Favorite food are Mikan and bell pepper stuffed with meat",
                    "Lightstick Colors are red and white",
                    "Favorite color is mustard yellow",
                    "Favorite Nogizaka46song is Arigachi na Renai",
                    "Her favorite animes are 86 Eighty Six, Vivy and No Game No Life",
                    "She likes anime songs, vocaloid, Yonezu Kenshi and Yorushika",
                    "Her favorite mangas are Magi and Tokimeki Tonight",
                    "She was the first Nogizaka46 5th Generation Member to be announced"
                ],
        "tv_participation": ["Nogizaka Shin Star Tanjo!",
                             "Nogizaka Under Construction",
                             "Music Blood"],
        "single_participation": ["Actually...",
                                 "Suki to Iu no wa Rock daze!",
                                 "Koko ni wa Nai Mono"],
        [...]
    }
```

Ideally, I want to be able to add links to specific words in the JSON file, and then render them as hyperlinks within pug.

As a more specific example:

```
block col-2
  ul
    each val in member.trivia
      li= val
```

I am trying to add hyperlinks to specific words within the JSON file, and then render them as hyperlinks within a Pug template. For example, I want to turn the words 'Mikan', 'Lightstick Colors', 'Arigachi na Renai' etc. into hyperlinks so that I can connect them to other pages. I have tried adding the hyperlink directly in the JSON file but it did not work. Is there a straightforward way to do this that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

If you store the full HTML anchor tag as escaped text within a JSON text string, you can use [unescaped interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped) to render the link:

**JSON**

```
{
  "myProperty": "Lorem <a href=\"#\">Ipsum</>"
}
```

**Pug**

```
ul
  li!= myProperty
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>Lorem <a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
```

It's not very pretty though. And be sure to heed the warnings about unescaped interpolation on that page in the Pug docs.

Is there a reason you're writing and storing the blog data in JSON and not in Pug?

Comment: Hi Sean, thank you a lot for the answer!

This is a template for a collection of **many** pages that present information in the same layout. I imagined it was more optimal to then create a template that just takes info from the JSON instead of writing every single one of the pages. I'd be pretty happy to hear any suggestions though.

Comment: Check out [Pug template inheritance](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html). I'd highly recommend creating a template Pug file with the page layout, then having individual Pug pages that extend that template. Would let you use actual markup for the content while keeping the page layout in one file.